# Easily readable font with visible differences between lowercase 'l' and uppercase 'I'

Tags: font

I'm looking for a professional-looking font to use in Microsoft Excel and Google Sheets that allows me to easily distinguish between a lowercase `l` and an uppercase `I` at a glance.

Every font I've tried either makes makes the two characters look near-identical (*Arial*, *Calibri*, *Cambria*), doesn't look professional (*Comic Sans*, *Courier*), or isn't easy to read in a spreadsheet (*Times New Roman*).

[image: Comparison of fonts]

Are there any good fonts that meet these requirements?

Comment: I've added my own answer below not as a definitive answer, but as the best option I've personally been able to find.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [multi-media content](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/935/185), etc. Concerning fonts, especially see [Would icon and font library questions be on topic?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/935/185)

Comment: Search the web for ["fonts for programmers"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=fonts+for+programmers&t=iphone&ia=web). Individual character legibility and distinctiveness ( I vs L vs 1 ) is critical for programmers/developers. Tips: the commercial font [*Pragmata*](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fsd/pragmata/) and open-source font [*Hack*](http://sourcefoundry.org/hack/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the font **Verdana** would be best.

It is a very professional looking font, at least in my opinion, and is completely distinguishable between the simmilar-looking characters.

It is available in both Google Sheets and Windows.

[image]

Comment: Demonstrating the 1 character is also distinct is a great idea. I'm tempted to amend my question to include that point.

Answer (score 0):

## Cambria

[image: Cambria comparison]

Cambria is a widely accepted professional font has been a [Standard Windows Font since Vista](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/fonts.htm), is [bundled alongside Microsoft Office for Mac](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1493) since 2007, and is part of the default font list in Google Docs.

While the the `l` and `I` characters are fairly similar, they should be distinct enough that you can tell the difference after using it for long enough.